# SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using svg in my application and i creating the path dynamically in my application and its working fine but in browser console it throws an error like `SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed`. I searched lot but i didn't found any better solution.

This is my code to create svg path dynamically

```
var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
path.setAttribute("d", "path data(Path is too long so can't provide here)");
path.setAttribute("fill", "green");  
path.setAttribute("stroke", "red");   
path.setAttribute("stroke-width", "3");    
$('#svgContainer').appendChild(path);
```

How to overcome this error and Is there any thing i need to change in my code?
Is there any thing i need to add to recover from this error?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: The error says "incorrect path format", so you have to show the value you pass as a path ,-)

Comment: @Sirko, I have posted my path here http://jsfiddle.net/L3wcV/ .

Comment: That's actually multiple paths. AFAIK `z` or `Z` has to be the last command within a path. Afterwards you start a new path, which should have its own element.

Comment: @Sirko i deleted z, but now also its throwing the same error.

Comment: That's not true, you can have multiple z or Z in a single path element.

Comment: Just one or all occurrences? Have you tried your path with static SVG before, just to make sure it works in theory and to narrow down the problem?

Comment: @Sirko can you please elaborate you comment.

Comment: Currently you want to add your `<path>` elements dynamically. I suggest you try to build a static SVG manually with the same data to check, if that works. According to Robert my knowledge about the occurrences of `z` in a path is wrong anyway, so this might be an approach to spot another error.

Comment: @Sirko, Now i have done with your instructions but i got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs at or just before this point: `L 512.888916015625,192.22222900390625`

Looks like you have the wrong number of values for the prior command which I think is `C 512.888916015625,192.88888549804687 512.888916015625,193.55555725097656...`

[The number of values between the C and the L must be divisible by 6](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands), You have 25 pairs unless I miscounted i.e. 50 values which is not divisible by 6.